# How to correctly override mousePressEvent in qquickwindow?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I have an object inherited from `qquickwindow` with an overridden `mousePressEvent` method.

.h

```
class FWindow : public QQuickWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FWindow(QQuickWindow* parent = Q_NULLPTR);

protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
};
```

.cpp

```
void FWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        ...
    }
    QQuickWindow::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

The problem is that when I add a `Rectangle` with `MouseArea` to a qml file, it does not react in any way. The signal goes to `FWindow`, not `MouseArea`. How to fix it?

.qml

```
FWindow
{
    visible: true;

    Rectangle
    {
        width: 50;
        height: 50;
        color: "green";

        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent;

            onClicked:
            {
                console.log("clicked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me correctly,  probably in the code that does not show this error, the mousePressEvent method is the following:  `void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override{
        qDebug() << event;
        QQuickWindow::mousePressEvent(event);
    }`, getting in the console: `QMouseEvent(MouseButtonPress, LeftButton, localPos=359,245, screenPos=359,274)
QMouseEvent(MouseButtonPress, LeftButton, localPos=320,245, screenPos=320,274)
qml: clicked
QMouseEvent(MouseButtonPress, LeftButton, localPos=320,244, screenPos=320,273, flags=MouseEventCreatedDoubleClick)
qml: clicked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#mousePressEvent) says that the received `QMouseEvent* event` in `QQuickItem::mousePressEvent` is accepted by default, if you don't want to accept it you must call `event->ignore()`.

Comment: I added event->ignore() to mousePressEvent. It still doesn't work.

Comment: And I use QQuickWindow, not QQuickItem.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.12.0 . . .

Comment: That's strange, I tested it and the `MouseArea` prints "clicked" as expected. Have you tried changing `console.log` to `console.error`, or changing the `Rectangle` color on click. It might happen that some times `console.log` doesn't print for some reason.

Comment: When I click on the green rectangle is activated FWindow::mousePressEvent, not MouseArea.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, have you tried to change those things?

Comment: Your code example already works for me, I submitted my answer before even trying thinking it was the missing `ignore()` but it's not really. It's probably something else in your code.

Comment: Finally. I'm stupid. I have two methods overridden by `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. I forgot to add `Quickwindow::mouseReleaseEvent(event)` to `FWindow::mouseReleaseEvent` and it didn't work because of that. And in the end, the code works. Thanks for your help.